# Change the buttons if user is logged

Tags: asp.net

I have this navbar which shows some links on the left side and Sign in/sign up links on the right one. I want to check if the user is logged and if it is, instead of the sign in/up links, to show his name. I know how to check if there is something in the session in the code behind, but I have a hard time changing the view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline code,

```
<% if (Session["User"] != null) { %>
//button goes here
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this the best way?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any concerns?

Comment: No, I was just curious. Thank you!

Comment: Where does `Session["User"]` come from? So OP must create a Session just to show a button?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. It uses the build in `Request.IsAuthenticated` to show/hide controls on the page. And you can use the `LoginStatus` Control for generating a login/logout link. See [Microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Login.aspx">Login</asp:HyperLink>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HyperLink1.Visible = false;
        Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```